# Python selenium - drag and drop slide bar without any iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, selenium-chromedriver, slider

I am practising my test automation on [seleniumeasy.com](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-drop-range-sliders-demo.html)
I reached drag and drop slide bar but couldn't figure out how to move the bar value from 10 to 80.
This is the code which I wrote but failed:

---

```
drag_ten = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value=10]")
drop_eighty = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value=80]")

ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(drag_ten, drop_eighty).perform()
```

---

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One slider is still a single web element. Only the attributes values of that element are changing, when you shift the slider left or right. So in your code, drop_eighty would be undefined at the time of execution.

You could use **drag_and_drop_by_offset** or **click_and_hold** and specify the offset to slide the slider

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-drop-range-sliders-demo.html')

slider = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="slider1"]//input')
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(slider, 250, 0).perform()
# Alternative: ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(250, 0).release().perform()
```

However, finding a proper offset value is not that simple. It may also vary based on the window size. There are ways to calculate it, but it would complicate the answer too much.

A simpler option, in that case, would be to use the JavascriptExecutors **execute_script** method to change the value and then trigger the onchange listener. This option uses more meaningful values but it is specific to your slider implementation and it would need to be adjusted for any other slider implementations.

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = 80;', slider)
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].onchange();', slider)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to to move the slider now. much appreciated.